# how to combine these arrays into one array?

Tags: php, arrays

how to combine these arrays into one array? without looping?
and for where in mysql?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 82
            [1] => 115
            [2] => 116
            [3] => 117
            [4] => 118
            [5] => 119
            [6] => 120
            [7] => 121
            [8] => 122
            [9] => 123
            [10] => 124
            [11] => 125
            [12] => 126
            [13] => 127
            [14] => 128
            [15] => 129
            [16] => 130
            [17] => 131
            [18] => 132
            [19] => 133
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 83
            [1] => 134
            [2] => 135
            [3] => 136
            [4] => 137
            [5] => 138
            [6] => 139
            [7] => 140
            [8] => 141
            [9] => 142
            [10] => 143
            [11] => 144
            [12] => 145
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 84
            [1] => 146
            [2] => 147
            [3] => 148
            [4] => 149
            [5] => 150
            [6] => 151
            [7] => 152
            [8] => 153
            [9] => 154
            [10] => 155
            [11] => 156
            [12] => 157
            [13] => 158
            [14] => 159
            [15] => 160
            [16] => 161
            [17] => 162
            [18] => 163
            [19] => 164
            [20] => 165
        )

)
```

Comment: use array_merge http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Don't repeat the same thing over and over. Describe your issue and show your code. `where in mysql`... what mysql? This is just an array..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$array  = your array

$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use array merge.

Here's the syntax: `array array_merge ( array $array1 [, array $... ] )`

However, remember there are certain rules with this. Identical String values will be overwritten and identical numeric values will be appended.